# Excel formula for transferring over column values from multiple sheets but having no multiple value transferred over

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel formula to take values from multiple sheets' cell (ie. 'S1'!A3,'S2'!A3,'S3'!A3), program to filter if there is        in cell, if not, move on to next sheet/if yes, get value; end program

imgs

MAIN Sheet: https://i.imgur.com/gNjRCr3

Sheet 1 - Monday: https://i.imgur.com/BX4lwu9

Sheet 2 - Tuesday: https://i.imgur.com/wtt8o8w

Sheet 3 - Wednesday: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTVfb.jpg

Comment: This can be done over several cells using the `INDIRECT` formula. If you want it all in one cell, you'll probably need VBA.

Comment: And do what with the values? Sum, list,...

Answer (score 0):

Possible to do without VBA for known number of sheets, although not very pretty:

```
= IF(NOT(ISBLANK(S1!A3)),S1!A3,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(S2!A3)),S2!A3,...etc...))
```

Use as many nested `IF`'s as necessary.

Comment: That will return only the first non blank in order.  That may be what the OP wants, but as I read it I see they want all the non-blanks not just one.  But, I may be wrong.

Comment: @ScottCraner "*That will return only the first non blank in order.*" That is how I interpreted the question. *program to filter if there is 'value' in cell, if not, move on to next sheet/if yes, get value*

Comment: I am going of the first sentence `Excel formula to take values from multiple sheets'` and then the OP uses the word filter, which means to me remove all blanks and return the rest.  But again I may be wrong.  Just expressing my opinion.

Comment: @ScottCraner Guess we'll find out soon enough!

Comment: sorry...having trouble explaining...trying to get <column A> values from Mon, Tue, Wed sheets to <column A> on MAIN sheet; so like if A2 has value: 1 across all other sheets, it'll just put value: 1 on the Main sheet A2; however, sometimes we have more or different values in the columns that don't correspond with the other sheets but we would like to put the value in <column A> of Main sheet as well...